# Getting error while setting up dot net core project in local

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to setup official .Net core solution in my local by doing git clone https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.git

As mentioned in the docs when I run below command:
.\restore.cmd

I get the following error

> Could not find an installation of MSBuild which satisfies the
>   requirements specified in korebuild.json. At
>   C:\Users\mritunjai_pratapsing\source\repos\Learning\AspNetCore.dotnet\buildtools\korebuild\3.0.0-build-20190412.2\scripts\KoreBuild.psm1:524
>   char:5
>   +     throw 'Could not find an installation of MSBuild which satisfies  ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Could not find ...korebuild.json.:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Could not find an installation of MSBuild which satisfies the requirements specified in korebuild.json.

Please comment if any other info is required.

Comment: Try this instead:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows .  Install .net core from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Comment: Hey @kristianp thanks for replying. I have all the required sdk in my system. I am trying to clone .Net core project to see how it is written and want to try few things. I am not creating a new project. I am trying below steps: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/docs/BuildFromSource.md